# How do I fire an on-Click listener ONLY IF previous on-Click listener is fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So what I want to accomplish is this: I have a dropdown *parent* called `.has-sub > a`, aka `link`. When `link` is clicked, then dropdown menu `.dplst` appears. When any element besides `link` and `.dplst` is clicked on, I want my alert function to pop-up, **HOWEVER, I ONLY want the alert to pop-up ONLY IF `link` has been clicked on**. So my problem lies in my jquery code. My error is when any elements besides `link` and `.dplst` are clicked on, and when `link` HASN'T been clicked, the alert function will pop-up. But I ONLY want it to pop up when `link` is clicked on. How do I do that with my current code? Please help me. Thank you

EDIT: So basically this is result I want:

1) Click on `.has-sub > a`

2) `.dplst` shows

3) click any element that does not have class `.alerts` and `$(".alerts").children()`

4) `.dplst` now hides

5) an alert dialogue pops up with text "ok"

**What I want to AVOID:**

1) don't do this - SKIP

2) don't do this - SKIP

[So basically Step #3 now becomes Step #1]

3) click any element that does not have class `.alerts` and `$(".alerts").children()`

4) this does not happen - SKIP

[And Step #5 becomes Step #2]

5) an alert dialogue pops up with text "ok"

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.flx2 > div > a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
    var checkElement = $(this).next();
    if((checkElement.is('.dplst')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
      $('.dplst:visible').slideUp('normal'); 
      checkElement.slideDown('normal');
    }
    if($(this).closest('div').find('.dplst').children().length == 0) { 
      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    if($('.flx2 > div > a').data('clicked')) {
      var dplst = $(".dplst");
      var alerts = $(".alerts").children().addBack();
      if (!dplst.is(e.target) && dplst.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        dplst.hide();
      }
      if (!alerts.is(e.target)) {
        $("button[name='altbut']").click();
      }
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button[name='altbut']").on('click', function(e) {
    alert("ok");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flx2">
  <div class='has-sub alerts'>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <div class="dplst">
      <a>text1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button name="altbut" type="button"></button>
```

Comment: This is a little word-salad like. Can you try and clear it up a little for clarity?

Comment: @AustinTFrench Clear up the description or the jquery code?

Comment: The question. It reads like a run on sentence and although I think I get the gist, I also have had to read it like 3 times.

Comment: @AustinTFrench I posted the edit, do I still need to clarify anything?

Answer (score 0):

Ok let me clear the situation here first,

So requirements is to show popup when 'link' has been clicked at least once and 'link' OR 'dplst' are not clicked and click has been made on '.flx2'

If I got the requirements right, then you can just add a hidden field, set value to 0, and when link is clicked change that value to 1. Then check for click on .flx2 and NOT(link OR dplst) and check if hidden value is 1, then show the popup otherwise not.

You can do something like this:

HTML

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="flx2">
      <div class='has-sub alerts'>
        <a id="link" href="#">link</a>
        <div class="dplst">
          <input type="hidden" id="linkClicked" value="0"/>
          <a>text1</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button name="altbut" type="button"></button>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('#link').on('click', function(e) {
   $('#linkClicked').val(1);
  });

   $(".flx2").click(function(e) {
        if($(e.target).is('.dplst') || $(e.target).is('#link')){
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
        else if($('#linkClicked').val() == 1){
            alert("woohoo!");
         }

    }); 

});
```

Fixed code above, also created a fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/63tgLz4u/

Comment: I tried this out and it's not working. When I click on `link`, the page refreshes when it should be showing the dropdown, `.dplst`. And because the page refreshes, the alert does not show

Comment: Sorry I didn’t test the code..  please change link as follow

' <a id="link" href="#">link</a>'

Note:- code for onclick to show .dplst is not included in my code, that has to be used from your own code, ALSO I would recommend not using <a> tag but use a normal span or label or something similar, if you have to underline it use CSS.. but its just my recommendation

Comment: I tested just now, and that fixed the page from refreshing, but the alert does not pop up

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.flx2 > div > a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
    var checkElement = $(this).next();
    if((checkElement.is('.dplst')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
      $('.dplst:visible').slideUp('normal'); 
      checkElement.slideDown('normal');
    }
    if($(this).closest('div').find('.dplst').children().length == 0) { 
      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    }
  });
  
  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    if($('.flx2 > div > a').data('clicked')) {
      var dplst = $(".dplst");
      var alerts = $(".alerts").children().addBack();
      if (!dplst.is(e.target) && dplst.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        dplst.hide();
        //set link data click to false
        $('.flx2 > div > a').data('clicked', false)
      }
      if (!alerts.is(e.target)) {
        $("button[name='altbut']").click();
      }
    }
  });
  
  $("button[name='altbut']").on('click', function(e) {
    alert("ok");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flx2">
  <div class='has-sub alerts'>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <div class="dplst">
      <a>text1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button name="altbut" type="button">button</button>
```

Don't know whether this match what are you want, your description is so mess...
there are few questions:
1. if dropdown been hide, are you going to show popup when click on link?
I add //set link data click to false inside code.